# Tense in noun modifying clauses?

Tags: tense, nouns, modification

When modifying nouns, if the noun you're modifying is a person, can the noun modifying clause be past tense? So if I wanted to say:

> The person I saw yesterday is here again today.

Which is correct?

> 1. 私が昨日に**見る**人はまた今日にはここでいる。
> 2. 私が昨日に**見た**人はまた今日にはここでいる。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case past tense 見た人 is correct and it's irrelevant if it's a person or an inanimate object.

But there are more points to be careful about in your sentence:

- no need to use に after the 昨日
- いる is a state verb, so it should be ここにいる (instead of ここで)
- also no need for に after 今日, in fact you would want to stress the fact it happens again, so も fits here

> 私が昨日見た人は、今日もまたここにいる。